# Almost everywhere growth of continued fraction partial quotients

Tags: continued-fractions

What is an upper bound for the growth of the largest partial quotient (i.e. the 'digit') among the first $n$ partial quotients in the continued fraction expansion of almost all real numbers as $n$ tends to infinity?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khinchin's_constant

Comment: Thank you. From this I can only see the obvious exponential bound. Is this best possible?